# Synchronizing access to a collection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I have these two pieces of code that could possibly be run at the same time on two different threads:

```
users = (from user in users
         orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending ,
                 user.Username
         select user).ToList();
```

and:

```
users=null;
```

The second piece of code will run on the main UI thread of the application. How can I prevent users to be set to null before the LINQ operation completes? Encapsulating the user collection in a property with locks on the getter and setter will not be enough methinks...

EDIT:
I constructed the following testing classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultiThreading_Spike
{
    class Program
    {
        private static List<User> users;
        private static Timer timer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            timer=new Timer(OrderUsers,null,5,5);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                ResetUsers();
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                users = new List<User>
                            {
                                new User {UserName = "John"},
                                new User {UserName = "Peter"},
                                new User {UserName = "Vince"},
                                new User {UserName = "Mike"}
                            };
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
            ResetUsers();
            Thread.Sleep(5)
            Debug.Assert(users==null);
        }

        private static void OrderUsers(object state)
        {
            if(users==null)return;
            Thread.Sleep(2);
            try
            {
                users = (from user in users
                         orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending ,
                             user.UserName
                         select user).ToList();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void ResetUsers()
        {
            users = null;
        }
    }


    public class User
    {
        bool isLoggedIn;
        public bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get { return isLoggedIn; }
            set { isLoggedIn = value; }

        }

        private string userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return userName; }
            set { userName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

This code fails with a null reference exception in the OrderUsers method.
Then I implemented the suggested solutions:
Solution 1:

```
//identical code omitted
        private static void OrderUsers(object state)
        {
         lock(syncRoot)
         {
            if(users==null)return;
            Thread.Sleep(2);
            try
            {
                users = (from user in users
                         orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending ,
                             user.UserName
                         select user).ToList();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",e.Message);
            }
         }
      }

        private static void ResetUsers()
        {
            lock(syncRoot)
            {
               users = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

No exceptions!

Solution 2:

```
   private static void OrderUsers(object state)
    {
        if(users==null)return;
        var tempUsers = users;
        Thread.Sleep(2);
        try
        {
            tempUsers = (from user in tempUsers
                     orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending ,
                         user.UserName
                     select user).ToList();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",e.Message);
        }
        users = tempUsers;
    }
```

No null reference exceptions, but the Assert for users to be null in the end can fail.

Solution 3:

```
private static void OrderUsers(object state)
        {
            if(users==null)return;
            try
            {
                users.Sort((a, b) => Math.Sign(-2 * a.IsLoggedIn.CompareTo(b.IsLoggedIn) + a.UserName.CompareTo(b.UserName)));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",e.Message);
            }
        }
```

No exceptions. I keep having the nagging feeling that the Sort may be "in place", but that it is not necessarily atomic.

Solution 4:
I could not get it to compile. The VolatileRead method has an overload taking an object, but I could not make it accept a List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to lock before executing your linq query and before setting to null:

```
lock(syncRoot) 
{
    users = null;
}
```

and

```
lock(syncRoot) 
{
    users = 
        (from user in users
         orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending,
                 user.Username
         select user).ToList(); 
}
```

where syncRoot:

```
private static syncRoot = new object();
```

Comment: Bleh! Foo! syncRoot shouldn't be static unless users is.

Comment: If "users" is local to a method then there's no need to lock on it.

Comment: @darin: The whole point is that `users` is also assigned to by another thread.  Read the question.

Answer (score 2):

Save the users to a local variable and operator on it, this way you won't have to sync anything.

```
var tempUsers = users;
if (tempUsers != null)
{
    tempUsers = (from user in tempUsers
             orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending, user.Username
             select user).ToList()
}
```

Comment: I would have to finish by assigning tempUsers to users,right? If so, I would have to check for null first, because I don't want to fill the users collection once it has been set to null; Couldn't users be set to null then right after the check for it by the other thread?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to call `List<T>.Sort`, which sorts the list in-place and does not require an assignment.

For example:

```
users.Sort((a, b) => Math.Sign(
    -2 * a.IsLoggedIn.CompareTo(b.IsLoggedIn) + a.UserName.CompareTo(b.UserName)
));
```

(This example assumes that none of the users are null)

If, while this is executing, another thread executes `users = null`, the old `List<T>` will be sorted, but the `users` variable will not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ query will *complete* whether or not the `users` variable is reset to null because `ToList()` forces eager evaluation.  However, I'm not sure that this will address your issue: if I understand correctly, you want to ensure that a stale collection is not left lying around in `users` because the set to `null` happened too early.

In this case, you can probably get away with just declaring a users-lock object and synchronizing on it both in the setter and around the query-and-set statement.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter much what you lock, as long as the two threads agree to lock the same thing.

Personally, I would use local variables and lock free operations:

```
var localUsers = Thread.VolatileRead(ref users);
do
{
  if (null == localUsers)
  {
    break;
  }

  var newLocalUsers = (from user in localUsers 
        orderby user.IsLoggedIn descending ,                 
        user.Username         
        select user).ToList();

  var currentLocalUsers = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref users, newLocalUsers, localUsers);
  if (currentLocalUsers == localUsers)
  {
    break;
  }
  // bummer, try again
  localUsers = currentLocalUsers;
} while(true);
```

And the other thread:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref users, null);
```

I have never tryed using Interlocked with `var` types, not sure how the compiler accepts it or does it has to be downcasted to `object`.

Comment: "var" is not a type. "var" simply means "compiler, the type of this variable is the type of its initializer".

Comment: @Eric: I was more wondering if the `Interlocked.CompareExchange<T>()` generic will be able to match the type of the `List<T>` from the linq result with whatever type `users` is *and* and `VolatileRead` return type. The later being `object`, I think some casts will be needed.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The interlocked methods are the least of your worries in that case. If users and localUsers are both typed as object, how is the compiler supposed to figure out what the query comprehension means? Before you start worrying about the type of the result of the query, you have to be able to work out the meaning of the query!